# Keep same value of all merged cells

Tags: excel

I don't know why every time I fall in love with a program because I found it very useful at first use, but I end up always struggling of its stupidity after a depth use.

So, my journey begins with the excel function "Merge & Center" that warns me that it will only keep the top left value and delete the others, which is very stupid because I can no longer drag a function in a cell to the others, did no one in this planet suggested that it will be way easier to keep the same value in each merged cells or to put at least a simple checkbox to give the user the option to choose between the two outcomes.

Ok, before I come to this forum I did some research, found a lot of VBA codes, tricks, methods but none gave me the satisfaction that I'm looking for, I concluded that it's impossible to merge and keep values in cells, so can someone please explain to me why Microsoft didn't think of that?

Here is a simple example of what I'm looking for:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBWNu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching all over the internet, I didn't find the perfect solution, so I started learning VBA and I made this beautiful function, it detects if cells are merged or not and if so then it returns the top cell value.

```
Function Merg(CellRef As Range) As String 

Dim MainCell As String 

If CellRef.MergeCells Then 
  MainCell = Left(CellRef.MergeArea.Address, InStr(1,CellRef.MergeArea.Address, ":") - 1)
Else 
  MainCell = CellRef.Address 
End If 

Merg = Range(MainCell).Value 

End Function
```

I don't know how to display the code properly on Stackoverflow. It's always a nightmare for me to understand the mechanics, you can visit my same thread on Microsoft [Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/keep-values-of-merged-cells/6dd7193b-e74e-4af4-a9de-fe956f75c891?messageId=edbc455a-8a79-450e-9654-65c986b6636c).

Comment: There is a [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) if you wish to have a play with the different posting features of the site. In your case, I used the `{}` button on the edit bar to put your code into a code block.

Comment: I tried that but it only works with the first line

Comment: Ah, you have to select the *entire* chunk of text you want in the code block, then hit the `{}` button.

Comment: For some reason I didn't think about that, thx ^^

Answer (score 1):

As you came to understand, merged cells are Excel's and VBA's worst nightmares! Avoid them (since they also make for terrible datastructures) if you can.

If you must use them and you need a function you can drag down, you'll need to make sure you create a mechanic that can skip certain rows. `INDEX()` is able to retrieve values with a 2nd parameter that tells the function which row you would like from a given array. If we make sure that this 2nd parameter has a steady incline we can still retrieve the correct values:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1-MOD(ROW()-1,3)+1)&B1
```

Comment: thank you for replying, unfortunately in my real case, A to F groups doesn't have the same length, also I have sub groups which will make this more difficult and the amount of data is large.